# haxe - How to automatically cast types for prototype clone() function?

Tags: inheritance, casting, clone, haxe

I have one prototype class that is desribed like:

```
class CEnumList<T:EnumValue> {
    ...
    public function clone():CEnumList<T> {
        var result:CEnumList<T> = new CEnumList<T>();
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Clone method implements standard procedure of creating a full copy of the instance. And I have one inherited class:

```
class CElements extends CEnumList<EElements> {
    ...
}
```

Where EElements is enum type. But when I call somewhere:

```
var damage:CElements = baseDamage.clone();
```

I have an error "data.CEnumList should be data.char.CElements" and that's absolutely correct. But how I should inherit prototype clone() method if my inherited classes differs only by  enum types? Should I create as many clone() methods as I have different classes and all these methods will just cast type of the private base class cloning?

Probably it isn't a question about haxe at all but question about application architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to return exactly CElements then yes, you will need another clone method that returns CElements.

But you may want not to **extend** CEnumList but to **typedef** it like this

```
typedef CElements = CEnumList<EElements>;
```

That should do the trick because the result will be correctly typed (as types will be identical, `typedef` just gives a synonym).